# Android - support.v7.PreferenceCategory fill the whole screen

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I am using support preference library and every `PreferenceCategory` fill the whole screen with blank space and then show the preferences that it contains. I have tried changing `PreferenceCategory` style attribute - layout_height to wrap_content and it didn't work.

My preference styles:

```
 <style name="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="preferenceScreenStyle">@style/Preference.PreferenceScreen</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentStyle">@style/PreferenceFragment</item>
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/Preference.Category</item>
    <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/Preference</item>
    <item name="preferenceInformationStyle">@style/Preference.Information</item>
    <item name="checkBoxPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.CheckBoxPreference</item>
    <item name="switchPreferenceCompatStyle">@style/Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat</item>
    <item name="dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference</item>
    <item name="editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentListStyle">@style/PreferenceFragmentList</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@color/dark_gray</item>
</style>
```

My prefernce xml:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
    android:key="pref_user_settings"
    android:title="@string/pref_group_user">
    <android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="Publisher"
        android:entries="@array/pref_user_types"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_user_types"
        android:key="pref_user_type"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_user_type" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
```

This is how it looks:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Preferences need to be defined in `/res/xml` not in `/res/layout` and used inside a `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceActivity`. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) for an example.

Comment: They are defined in `/res/xml` and inside `PreferenceFragment`.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am trying to fix it without success.

Comment: @DannyHambourg have you been able to fix this problem? It gives Me headaches. I spend several days trying to fix it but don't get it.

Comment: @AnderAcosta I've added an answer. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i solved it out is customing the preference category file.

**Solution:**

Create a new layout xml file called custom_preference_category:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:id="@android:id/title" />
```

Then add this to your styles file:

```
<style name="Preference.Category">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/custom_preference_category</item>
    <item name="android:shouldDisableView">false</item>
    <item name="android:selectable">false</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="preferenceScreenStyle">@style/Preference.PreferenceScreen</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentStyle">@style/PreferenceFragment</item>
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/Preference.Category</item>
    <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/Preference</item>
    <item name="preferenceInformationStyle">@style/Preference.Information</item>
    <item name="checkBoxPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.CheckBoxPreference</item>
    <item name="switchPreferenceCompatStyle">@style/Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat</item>
    <item name="dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference</item>
    <item name="editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference
    </item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentListStyle">@style/PreferenceFragmentList</item>
</style>
```

And then use this style in your main app theme:

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
```

I did it a lot of time ago so I'm not sure if this all I've done, so give me a feedback if something is missing.